# Cannot get Jest & React Native working

Tags: react-native, jestjs, babel-jest

Trying to get Jest v12.1.1 working with React Native v0.26.2 I'm getting this error when run `npm test`:

`Error: Cannot find module 'ErrorUtils' from 'env.js'`

Here's my `package.json`. I'm trying to get this working with the default `react-native init AwesomeProject` starter.

Is there something missing from my package.json? (are here any lines I don't need?)

**EXAMPLE 1:**

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "AwesomeProject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.0.2",
    "react-native": "^0.26.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "^9.0.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "*",
    "babel-preset-react": "*",
    "jest-cli": "^12.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "jest": {   
    "scriptPreprocessor": "node_modules/react-native/jestSupport/preprocessor.js",
    "setupEnvScriptFile": "node_modules/react-native/jestSupport/env.js",        
    "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
      "/node_modules/",
      "/android/",
      "/ios/",
      "/.idea/"
    ],    
    "testFileExtensions": [
      "js"
    ],
    "unmockedModulePathPatterns": [
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/react/",
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-dom/",
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-addons-test-utils/"
    ],    
    "verbose": true
  }
}
```

Here's a test script.

**index.android-test.js**

```
// __tests__/index.android-test.js

'use strict';

jest
  .disableAutomock()
  .setMock('AwesomeProject', {})
  .setMock('React', {Component: class {}});

describe('AwesomeProject', () => {

  it('test something', () => {
    const testJunk = true;

    expect(testJunk).toEqual(true);
  });

});
```

**EXAMPLE 2:**

I get a different error when I add "haste" to `package.json` and remove `scriptPreprocessor` & `setupEnvScriptFile`. 

`Error: Cannot find module 'AwesomeProject' from 'index.android-test.js'`

I have no clue why I get farther ahead with the following. My previous Example 1 is following: 
https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/tutorial-react.html#content
And Example 2 with 'haste` is following:
https://github.com/fbsamples/f8app/blob/master/package.json

Really confused about why Ex 1 doesn't work.

**revised package.json**

```
{
  "name": "AwesomeProject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.0.2",
    "react-native": "^0.26.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "^9.0.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "*",
    "babel-preset-react": "*",
    "jest-cli": "^12.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "jest": {   
    "haste": {
      "defaultPlatform": "android",
      "platforms": [
        "ios",
        "android"
      ],
      "providesModuleNodeModules": [
        "react-native"
      ]
    },    
    "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
      "/node_modules/",
      "/android/",
      "/ios/",
      "/.idea/"
    ],    
    "testFileExtensions": [
      "js"
    ],
    "unmockedModulePathPatterns": [
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/react/",
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-dom/",
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-addons-test-utils/"
    ],    
    "verbose": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Found similar issue with Jest and RN v0.26 on react-native GitHub: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+jest

Comment: did using Jest@11.x.x version work for you? Did you go with Example 1 or Example 2 (that you have listed) approach?