# React Native - __DEV__ is not defined

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-native

I have a react-native@0.26.2 project.
I have deleted the node_modules folder and after i have given the following commands:

```
npm i
react-native upgrade
```

but I get this error:

```
react-native.js:15 

ReferenceError: __DEV__ is not defined
```

How do I fix?

Comment: I get same error when running Jest. Trying to get Jest working, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37474160/cannot-get-jest-react-native-working `ReferenceError: __DEV__ is not defined`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ReferenceError: Can't find variable: \_\_DEV\_\_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33281733/referenceerror-cant-find-variable-dev)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maybe this? https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7814

> Removing .babelrc seems to fix the problem.
>
> My .babelrc:
>
> {   "presets": ["react-native"] }

Comment: Then I end up with this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53326986/trace-the-node-type-spreadproperty-has-been-renamed-to-spreadelement-at-object

Answer (score 25):

Adding

```
/* global __DEV__ */
```

To the top of the file worked for me.

Comment: What is this, can you explain?

Comment: Isn't this a eslint syntax? I don't think this does anything for compilation issues.

Answer (score 5):

Since this is the first search result, I wanted to drop another hint for those who are running into this issue with react-native-web and Jest.

As detailed in https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/1085, if you are mapping `'react-native'` to `'react-native-web'` in your build system (webpack, for me), then you also need that mapping in your Jest config.

I was seeing the

```
ReferenceError: __DEV__ is not defined
```

when I ran tests through Jest. Adding

```
moduleNameMapper: {
    '^react-native$': 'react-native-web',
}
```

to `jest.config.js` fixed this for me.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using `jest.config.js` file, then place this in that

```
globals: {
    __DEV__: true
},
```

It will work then. Happy :)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Have figured out the solution works on the entire project,just add `globals` property to the .eslintrc.json file:

```
{
    "rules":{
        //your rules
    },
    "globals": {
        "__DEV__": true
    }
}
```

Note that `globals` and `rules` should be in the same json object.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 1):

Adding 'babel-preset-react-native' to devDependencies solved this issue

Answer (score -3):

The .babelrc file is hidden in folder .
I just delete it and then my react native project work.