# Trace: The node type SpreadProperty has been renamed to SpreadElement at Object.isSpreadProperty

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I'm launching a react app, and here's my Webpack configuration:

```
'use strict'

const ExtractPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')
const HTMLPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
module.exports = {
    devtool: 'eval',
    entry: `${__dirname}/src/main.js`,
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle-[hash].js',
        path: `${__dirname}/build`,
        publicPath: '/',
    },
    mode: 'development',
    performance: {
        hints: false
    },
    plugins: [
        new HTMLPlugin(),
        new ExtractPlugin('bundle-[hash].css'),
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_module/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loader: ExtractPlugin.extract(['css-loader', 'sass-loader']),
            },
        ],
    },
}
```

Then, I have a package.json file, here are the dependencies:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.6",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.6",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "and": "0.0.3",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
    "eslint": "^5.9.0",
    "install": "^0.12.2",
    "jest": "^23.6.0",
    "npm": "^6.4.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-beta.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "react": "^16.6.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.3",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "webpack": "^4.25.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.10"
  }
```

I have tried plenty of ways of updating babel packages up to 7th version, changing babelrc config, what ever.

The project though compiles, but in the beginning of compilation I get the following message:

Trace: The node type SpreadProperty has been renamed to SpreadElement
    at Object.isSpreadProperty

And about of hundred rows like that. After all that rows being printed out, the compilation process proceeds and is completed successfully.

What's that and how can I get rid of this rows?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

here is the final setting that solved problem for me.

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread"
  ]
}
```

For a better understanding, here is my package.json's **devDependencies**:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.6",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-object-assign": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^7.1.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.6",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "8.0.4",
    "prop-types": "15.6.2",
    "react": "^16.6.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.3",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "utils": "^0.3.1",
    "webpack": "4.26.1",
    "webpack-cli": "3.1.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.10"
  }
```

Here is my **webpack.config.js** module's section:

```
module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/ ,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loaders: "babel-loader"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: not sure how this is not the accepted answer but this should have been it, I had updated to babel 7 but had not yet used the proper updated plugins

Answer (score 48):

This issue is occurring due to using outdated

```
`"babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread"`
```

update this in package.json

```
`"@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.0.0",`
```

and update your .babelrc.js file 
in my case it looks like this

```
const isTest = String(process.env.NODE_ENV) === 'test'
module.exports = {
  presets: [["@babel/env", { modules: isTest ? 'commonjs' : false }, "@babel/react"]],
  plugins: [
    'syntax-dynamic-import',
    'transform-class-properties',
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread',
  ],
}
```

this solves my problem

Answer (score 18):

Before in my .babelrc

i was using the plugin: `["transform-object-rest-spread", { "useBuiltIns": true }],`

then i switch it to `"@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread"` and all those warnings went away, which has been very nice.
`

Comment: Right, and in addition to the info - We can change this in either .babelrc or package.json whichever file is already having babel settings

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I was not implementing the Webpack configuration and still error was there. After so many solutions implementation, the error was same or once an error was removed another appeared. Finally, I deleted `.bablerc`, `.babelrc` and `package-lock.json` files and ran `rm -rf node_modules && npm install` and then ran `react-native run-android` and it worked for me. :-)

Comment: I believe the problem comes from using babel-preset-react-native, which depends on /babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread (an older version of @babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread). Rather than deleting the entire .babelrc, you should be able to just remove `react-native` from the presets.

Answer (score 4):

If nothing up here worked, Just remove plugins from old babel. In my case removing following spread plugin had disappeared the thing.

```
   plugins: ["transform-object-rest-spread"]
```