# The node type SpreadProperty has been renamed to SpreadElement

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I recently upgrade from React Native 0.53.3 to React Native 0.59.9 and my application keeps crashing inside of simulator. It will display the splash screen and then just crash with nothing inside of debugger-ui except for this:

> WebSocket connection to
> 'ws://localhost:8081/debugger-proxy?role=debugger&name=Chrome' failed:
> Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

I was running it with `react-native run-ios` but the build was succeeding there so no error message. When I tried to open the app while having Xcode open it did refer to an error of not being able to find the `.jsbundle` file and inside of Xcode, I do have a `main.jsbundle` in red, indicating it's missing.

So after finding this article:
https://medium.com/the-react-native-log/first-time-deploying-with-react-native-f524eb3e705d#59ee

I tried following it by utilizing a script of `npm run build:ios` which is referencing this script:

```
"build:ios": "react-native bundle --entry-file='index.ios.js' --bundle-output='./ios/NFIBEngage/main.jsbundle' --dev=false --platform='ios' --assets-dest='./ios'"
```

But when I run that, I get this error:

```
Loading dependency graph, done.
transform[stderr]: Trace: The node type SpreadProperty has been renamed to SpreadElement
transform[stderr]:     at Object.isSpreadProperty (/Users/danale/Projects/engage-application.mobile/node_modules/@babel/types/lib/validators/generated/index.js:4304:11)
transform[stderr]:     at hasSpread (/Users/danale/Projects/engage-application.mobile/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread/lib/index.js:38:13)
transform[stderr]:     at PluginPass.ObjectExpression (/Users/danale/Projects/engage-application.mobile/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread/lib/index.js:234:14)
transform[stderr]:     at newFn (/Users/danale/Projects/engage-application.mobile/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/visitors.js:193:21)
transform[stderr]:     at NodePath._call (/Users/danale/Projects/engage-application.mobile/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:53:20)
transform[stderr]:     at NodePath.call (/Users/danale/Projects/engage-application.mobile/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:40:17)
transform[stderr]:     at NodePath.visit (/Users/danale/Projects/engage-application.mobile/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:88:12)
transform[stderr]:     at TraversalContext.visitQueue (/Users/danale/Projects/engage-application.mobile/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:118:16)
transform[stderr]:     at TraversalContext.visitSingle (/Users/danale/Projects/engage-application.mobile/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:90:19)
transform[stderr]:     at TraversalContext.visit (/Users/danale/Projects/engage-application.mobile/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:146:19)
error node_modules/react-native-keyboard-manager/index.js: Cannot read property 'bindings' of null. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

The only post related to that error on SO is the one below:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53326986/trace-the-node-type-spreadproperty-has-been-renamed-to-spreadelement-at-object
```

and it does not really apply to my case.

The problem seems to be with a `@babel` library inside the `node_modules` which I have tried doing an `rm -rf node_modules`, but that did not resolve it.

Is one of these dev dependencies no longer supported in the current version of this project?

```
"devDependencies": {
    "async": "2.6.0",
    "babel-cli": "6.24.1",
    "babel-eslint": "8.0.2",
    "babel-jest": "23.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "3.0.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "1.4.0",
    "babel-preset-flow": "6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "6.24.1",
    "babel-watch": "2.0.6",
```

How can I resolve this issue (with upgrading to React Native 0.59.9)?

I have learned that after RN 0.49, we use `index.js` instead of `index.ios.js` and I verified this when I created a mock version to try to get a baseline application to try to figure out what is going on.

I did the following:

```
✗ mv index.ios.js index.js
➜  engage-application.mobile git:(feature/3.6.2_upgrade) ✗ rm index.android.js
➜  engage-application.mobile git:(feature/3.6.2_upgrade) ✗ react-native bundle --entry-file ./index.js --platform ios --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --verbose
Loading dependency graph, done.
transform[stderr]: Trace: The node type SpreadProperty has been renamed to SpreadElement
transform[stderr]:     at Object.isSpreadProperty (/Users/danale/Projects/engage-application.mobile/node_modules/@babel/types/lib/validators/generated/index.js:4304:11)
transform[stderr]:     at hasSpread (/Users/danale/Projects/engage-application.mobile/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread/lib/index.js:38:13)
transform[stderr]:     at PluginPass.ObjectExpression (/Users/danale/Projects/engage-application.mobile/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread/lib/index.js:234:14)
transform[stderr]:     at newFn (/Users/danale/Projects/engage-application.mobile/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/visitors.js:193:21)
transform[stderr]:     at NodePath._call (/Users/danale/Projects/engage-application.mobile/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:53:20)
transform[stderr]:     at NodePath.call (/Users/danale/Projects/engage-application.mobile/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:40:17)
transform[stderr]:     at NodePath.visit (/Users/danale/Projects/engage-application.mobile/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:88:12)
transform[stderr]:     at TraversalContext.visitQueue (/Users/danale/Projects/engage-application.mobile/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:118:16)
transform[stderr]:     at TraversalContext.visitSingle (/Users/danale/Projects/engage-application.mobile/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:90:19)
transform[stderr]:     at TraversalContext.visit (/Users/danale/Projects/engage-application.mobile/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:146:19)
error App.js: Cannot read property 'bindings' of null
debug TypeError: Cannot read property 'bindings' of null
    at Scope.moveBindingTo (/Users/danale/Projects/engage-application.mobile/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/scope/index.js:864:13)
    at BlockScoping.updateScopeInfo (/Users/danale/Projects/engage-application.mobile/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-block-scoping/lib/index.js:364:17)
```

and I still get the same error regardless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were actually two separate issues going on here. The

> WebSocket connection to
>   'ws://localhost:8081/debugger-proxy?role=debugger&name=Chrome' failed:
>   Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

error had to do with the fact that port 8081 was already in use so I had to kill all processes completely.

Definitely some dependency issues going on between Babel and one or two custom packages, which was primary `react-native-keyboard-manager` and `react-native-input-scroll-view`. I removed these and used `react-native`'s `ScrollView` instead.

I was then able to successfully run:

`react-native bundle --entry-file ./index.js --platform ios --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --verbose`

That was able to successfully create the `main.jsbundle`, but unfortunately that was not the root cause of the app crashing as it is still crashing and doing so silently now.