# react native web, __DEV__ not defined

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-web

If you want to share code between RN and RN-web, `__DEV__` should also be provided in the both platform.

However I can't add **DEV** using `const __DEV__ = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'; new webpack.DefinePlugin({__DEV__})`

I can set `window.__DEV__` fine, but RN code uses `__DEV__`

I've also tried adding `module:metro-react-native-babel-preset`

I've seen [React Native - __DEV__ is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37487492/react-native-dev-is-not-defined)

`/* global __DEV__ */` works, but hope there's a way to fix it without modifying all source which uses `__DEV__`

Answer (score 4):

in your `webpack.config.js`, add this:

```
  plugins: [
    // `process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'` must be `true` for production
    // builds to eliminate development checks and reduce build size. You may
    // wish to include additional optimizations.
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'),
      __DEV__: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' || true,
    }),
  ],
```

see https://medium.com/@alexander.forselius/experiment-combining-native-web-ios-android-and-macos-development-in-rectnative-part-1-ecd5887e9cfc

Comment: it seems there is a mistake that came from the blog post, I guess the condition must be:

`__DEV__: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'`

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by making it depend on the webpack mode input.

In `webpack.config.js`:

```
const config = {
  ...
  plugins: [],
  ...
}

module.exports = (env, argv) => {
  config.plugins.push(new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    __DEV__: JSON.stringify(argv.mode !== 'production'),
  }));

  return config;
};
```